# Group by and conditions in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with similar names, courses, lesson and completion.

```
name <- c("John", "John", "John", "Sam", "Sam")
course <- c("Driving", "Driving", "Driving", "Cycling", "Cycling")
lesson <- c("Gears", "Parking", "Overtaking", "Balancing", "Turning")
completion <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
df_school <- data.frame(name, course, lesson, completion)
```

I want to change all completion to 0 if a student has not completed any lesson. The output should be:

```
name <- c("John", "John", "John", "Sam", "Sam")
course <- c("Driving", "Driving", "Driving", "Cycling", "Cycling")
lesson <- c("Gears", "Parking", "Overtaking", "Balancing", "Turning")
completion <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
df_completed <- data.frame(name, course, lesson, completion)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

By `dplyr`

```
df_school %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(completion = +all(completion == 1))

  name  course  lesson     completion
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>
1 John  Driving Gears               0
2 John  Driving Parking             0
3 John  Driving Overtaking          0
4 Sam   Cycling Balancing           1
5 Sam   Cycling Turning             1
```

Answer (score 2):

With **`dplyr`**:

```
library(dplyr)
df_school %>% group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(completion=+(length(completion) == sum(completion)))
```

Output:

```
  name  course  lesson     completion
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>           <int>
1 John  Driving Gears               0
2 John  Driving Parking             0
3 John  Driving Overtaking          0
4 Sam   Cycling Balancing           1
5 Sam   Cycling Turning             1
```